# Destroy object in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How do you destroy an object created like below.  I may need to change pages depending on answer to prior pages:

```pascal
[Code]

var
  UninstallFirstPage: TNewNotebookPage;

procedure Whatever();
begin
  UninstallFirstPage := TNewNotebookPage.Create(UninstallProgressForm);
  UninstallFirstPage.Notebook := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
  UninstallFirstPage.Parent := UninstallProgressForm.InnerNotebook;
  UninstallFirstPage.Align := alClient;
   ...

  { How do you destruct UninstallFirstPage - may want to change it after created }

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Inno Setup Pascal Script (in Delphi/VCL), you destroy an object by calling its destructor, which has a name `Free`:

```pascal
UninstallFirstPage.Free;
```

A good practice is to reset the variable value afterwards:

```pascal
UninstallFirstPage := nil;
```